# Operators and Functions

Tags: functions, operator-theory

What is the exact difference between operators and functions ( if there is any ) ? Can i say an operator is more general than a function as it turns functions into functions ( like the derivative operator ) while the functions can't do that ?  So that would mean that you need an operator to turn a function into a function ? You can't create a function that takes a function ( domain set ) into another function (range set ) ?

Comment: From what I've seen, you don't bother putting brackets around operators and they usually get applied to more complex objects like functions etc.

Comment: The distinction, as far as I can tell, is historical. Of course every operator is also a function. "Operator" is intended to conjure up a specific context, nothing more.

Comment: Why can't i comment on my topic ? Anyways, this is for Qiaochi Yuan... Can i say every function is also an operator ? Can an operator transform vector spaces into vectors spaces as well ? Can a function transform vectors spaces into vectors as well ?

Comment: You can only comment on your own posts until you have a certain amount of reputation. It looks like you managed to get a duplicate account, so the system doesn't see this as "your own post."

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/66909/nerdy) is the account that posted the question. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/66708/nerdy) is your current account. They are different. Try following [these instructions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

Although the terminology varies, sometimes arbitrarily as the quote below illustrates, a linear operator is a linear transformation going from a vector space into itself & is thought of as operating on the domain (thus the end result must lie in the domain) while a general linear transformation can go between different vector spaces or act on the same vector space, [link](http://books.google.ie/books?id=Hg65zoqiUgoC&pg=PA315&dq=linear+operator+linear+map&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0GVDUaPWGayR7AbNkoHQDQ&ved=0CDcQuwUwAQ#v=onepage&q=linear%20operator%20linear%20map&f=false), & this idea is usually followed in books on functional analysis etc... but it's just terminology that's context-dependent & can vary depending on the biases of those using the words. As an example, in the book linked to above they say that an operator is defined as a linear transformation from a vector space back into itself, whereas in [this book](http://books.google.ie/books?id=xP0RFUHWQI0C&pg=PA103&dq=derivative+operator+linear+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JmlDUZqELLTB7AbFvIDoDw&ved=0CDYQuwUwAQ#v=onepage&q=derivative%20operator%20linear%20algebra&f=false) they define the derivative operator as acting between different vector spaces, so while it's alright to expect that the word operator means you're codomain is the same as your domain don't be surprised if it isn't.

> Some authors, such as Serge Lang, use "map" as a general term for an association of an element in the range with each element in the domain, and "function" only to refer to maps in which the range is a field.
>   [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_%28mathematics%29)